# What is the word that describes a word that is used in literature/writing, but not normally in common dialogue?

Tags: word-choice

The question says it all.

I see a lot of examples on this site of a word that is accepted for a question, but I would never hear that word in my life.  I may see it if I read something, but my friends, coworkers, and family would never use it.

Note:  Bonus if the word would not describe itself!

Comment: Bonus? You could offer a "bounty".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go for...

> [recherche](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/recherche) *- exotic or obscure.*
>    ...or...
>    [**recondite**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/recondite) *- difficult to understand; known only by experts.*

...either of which words could reasonably be used to describe the other.

Here are a few hundred written instances of [recondite vocabulary](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I%20love%20a%20man%20in%20uniform%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22recondite%20vocabulary%22&tbm=bks) to show it *is* used thus.

---

For a more common/informal alternative (i.e. - one which imho definitely *doesn't* "describe itself", OP could always say ["recondite" is a **highfalutin** word](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22highfalutin%20word%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (academics don't use that one, so they don't care if it's spelt *highfaluten, hifalutin, highfaluting,* or whatever).

Comment: Your last disclaiming sentence makes me wonder: are there other uses of ‘recondite’ that you feel are more common than this one? If I think of the word ‘recondite’, this usage (obscure/literary/academic vocabulary) is the very first association that comes to mind.

Comment: @Janus: I too tend to associate *recondite* with literature (probably because it was a favourite term with one of my Lit Crit lecturers back in the day). It also turns up in the closely-related context of [spiritual knowledge / wisdom](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22recondite+wisdom%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but to my mind it's more evocative of *academic* knowledge theoretically available to all, but in practice only of interest to a few. As opposed to *arcane*, which I tend to think of as *jealously guarded knowledge* (not normally available even if you *want* to access it).

Answer (score 6):

You are probably thinking of [*literary*:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/literary)

> 4.
>   a. Appropriate to literature rather than everyday speech or writing.
>   b. Bookish; pedantic.

It is often used in dictionaries to denote that a word is used more in writing than in normal speech. See, for example, [this definition](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/Tartuffe#m_en_us1297179) of *tartuffe*:

> noun 
> **literary** or humorous
>
> a religious hypocrite, or a hypocritical pretender to excellence of any kind.
>       [from the name of the principal character (a religious hypocrite) in Molière's Tartuffe (1664)]

If you want to be more caustic, you could say that people on this site deliberately use *[obfuscating](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/obfuscate)* language.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the adjective *academic*, which has these as definitions:

> [Learned or scholarly but lacking in worldliness, common sense, or practicality.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/academic)
>
> [Scholarly to the point of being unaware of the outside world.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/academic)

You could say that something was, for example, an *academic point*, an *academic argument*, or an *academic question*.

Comment: I think that word is definitely heading down the right track.

Comment: Be careful with its usage, though: there’s a hell of a difference between saying, “This is largely an academic debate” and saying, “This debate is largely academic”!

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to put down someone who uses such words:

**turgid** : Excessively ornate or complex in style or language; grandiloquent. Ostentatiously lofty in style. Excessively embellished in style or language.
*turgid prose / turgid speech / That hoity-toity Talia Ford is so over her head with that turgid, faux-intellectual swill that she takes for the English language.*